# .h file not found from dependent subproject in Xcode when archiving

Tags: xcode

When I try to Archive my Xcode project, it can no longer find the .h files from the subproject in the same workspace. It works fine otherwise.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had created a new build configuration on the main project and that same build configuration didn't exist in the subproject, so when it went to archive it couldn't find the .h files that had been copied over.

I added the same build configuration to the subproject and it archived just fine.

Comment: I'd love to know of a solution when you aren't able to modify the sub-project (i.e. because its a third party library from github.

Comment: Just fork the project on github and change it.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.